# React.JS, how to render a component from it's child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a nested tree of two components calling each other
 and

I'm trying to make the following nested components tree

```
<Option>
  <OptionContents>
   <Option>
     <OptionContents>
     ...
     </OptionContents>
   </Option>
  </OptionContents>
</Option>
```

But I'm getting 'Option' undefined, I know that it's because OptionContents is loaded before Option which leads to the undefined error. But is there a way to acheive this?

Comment: Are you importing `Option` from its own module or is it defined in the same file as the code you printed above?   If its in its separate module please ensure you are exporting it.

Comment: Yes it is in a separate module and I'm exporting it. This works <Option><OptionContents>test</OptionContents></Option>. By asa I call Option again inside OptionContents I get the undefined error. Note that I use gulp with reactify and browserify to generate the browser's JS

Comment: Are you importing `Option` in the `OptionContents` module? You need to import the components you want to use in each module. An imported module is not available to children.

Comment: @Mat Yes I do import `Option` in `OptionContents` and vice versa

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you're generating a circle dependency here. `OptionContents` renders `Option` which renders `OptionContents` which renders `Option` and so on... what's the reasoning for this structure? It seems broken.. maybe update your question to show us more code and the problem you're trying to solve on a higher level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might understand what you're trying to do. Assuming you have two components:

```
var Option = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<li>{this.props.children}</li>);
  }
});
```

and

```
var OptionContents = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<div>{this.props.children}</div>);
  }
});
```

And you'd like to use and re-use them (nesting and so on), you should import them both into a component which will render them.

```
// import Option
// import OptionContents
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Option>
        <OptionContents>
         <Option>
           <OptionContents>
           ...
           </OptionContents>
         </Option>
        </OptionContents>
      </Option>
    );
  }
});
```

As opposed to include them in each other as dependencies and trying to render.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem if you're using a parent component i.e:

```
import Option
import OptionContents

render() {
   return (
      <Option>
        <OptionContents>
         <Option>
           <OptionContents>
           ...
           </OptionContents>
         </Option>
        </OptionContents>
      </Option>
   );
}
```

This wouldn't have a circular conflict afaik..